# How can let variable in " Ext.Ajax.request " become Global variable?

Tags: extjs

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'a/b/c',
        success: function(response)
                {
                   var result = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
             if((result.a)==1)                            
              {
                 var value = result.a;
             }

                }
     });
```

If I want "value" become my golbal variable. 
How can I do ?
(PS:sorry,My English is not well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of `taox` is correct but I will explain why it don't work.

Make sure you are accessing the variable after the request had been made. Note that the request is made Asynchronous.

```
var value;
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'a/b/c',
    success: function(response){
          var result = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
          if((result.a)==1){
             value = result.a;
          }
    },
    callback: function(opt, succes, response){
        console.log(value); //value is now set
    }
});
console.log(value); //value isn't set
```

Edit:

To make a global variable in Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myValue = 'A1rPun'; //define variable
  function getValue()
  {
      console.log(myValue) //outputs "A1rPun"
      console.log(window.myValue) //outputs "A1rPun" (window is the topmost parent AKA global scope)
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I see. But the "value" only can use in "Ext.Ajax.request". It's still not golbal variable.

Comment: Updated answer. Please accept it if I answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can declare *value* as a global variable then assign result.a to it in your success function.

```
  var value;
  Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'a/b/c',
    success: function(response)
    {
          var result = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
          if((result.a)==1)                            
          {
             value = result.a;
          }

    }
  });
```

Comment: I try declare value.  But it still undefine.

Comment: Yes, `A1rPun` pointed out that your request is asyc so it's still undefined.